# Proving that $q(A,S)>0$ if $A>0$, $S<0$ and $p_i(A,S)>0$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, polynomials

Consider the polynomials
$$p_1=3(56-56A+A^2)-112(-6+A)S-14(-36+A)S^2+112S^3+7S^4,$$
$$p_2=-112(-6+A)-28(-36+A)S+336S^2+28S^3,$$
$$p_3=-28(-36+A)+672S+84S^2,$$
$$p_4=672+168S,$$
$$p_5=168,$$
$$q=-168S-252S^2-84S^3-7S^4+84A+84AS-3A^2+14AS^2.$$
I want to prove that if $A>0$, $S<0$ and $p_i>0$ then $q>0$.

I have observed that $\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial S}(A,S)=p_{i+1}(A,S)$ and $q=-p_1+p_2-p_3+p_4-p_5$, so we can express $q$ as
$$q=\sum_{k=0}^4(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\partial^k p_1}{\partial S^k},$$
but I don't know if it can be used to prove the above statement.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Equivalently, we wish to show that $q(A,S)>0$ for $0<A<28-2\sqrt{182}$ and $-1/3<S<0$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thank you for adding a comment :) In fact, I found a slightly different solution to the problem which resulted in these polynomial inequalities. So, this question may not be as relevant as it was before. But it is still worth thinking about it, and considering different points of view.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Were the bounds $28-2\sqrt{182}$ and $-1/3$ found by the reduction of the original inequalities using some computer algebra system?

Comment: @Tomi27 The bound $28-2\sqrt{182}$ was analytically derived by setting the constant term of $p_1$ to zero. The bound $-1/3$ was graphically obtained. I noticed that the domain in which $p_i>0$ became smaller as $i$ decreased; that is $\operatorname{dom}(p_1>0)\subset\operatorname{dom}(p_2>0)\subset\cdots\subset\operatorname{dom}(p_5>0)=\Bbb R$.